# How to find maximum observation length in a column?

Tags: sas

How to find maximum observation length within a column so that i am able to
apply formatted input while using input?

```
 data class;
 input name$;
 cards;
   Alfred
   Alice
   Barbara
   Carol
   Henry
 ;
 run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the retain function and traverse the observations:

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  retain max_name 0;
  if length(name)>max_name then do;
    max_name=length(name);
    call symput("max_name",put(max_name,best.));
  end;
run;
%put &max_name;
```

Just realised proc sql was easier:

```
proc sql;
  select max(length(name))
  from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Comment: For the proc sql version, try `select max(length(name)) into :macro_var` if you want to be able to use the retrieved value in subsequent code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **LENGTH** function to create a new column. Then you can find the maximum value using **MAX** function.

Additionally you can explore other options - LENGTHC, LENGTHM, LENGTHN.

Comment: Or use retain to keep the max value as you go (if length(name) > length_field then length_field = length(name). Then you only need to read in once and output the final row